# I want a macro that asks another player to move away from my area when I am waiting for a rare to pop

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am a beast master hunter and have an issue with other players who come into the area where the rare spawns. Since I have been waiting in that spot for some time for the spawn, I want to ask them to move away as nicely as possible.

Comment: While I share your pain about camping rare spawn pets, I've hunted many pets in my lifetime, and call me a cynic, but if someone else is also looking for that pet, what gives you more privileges than them? 

That said, this dude helps people out with server hopping and getting them. https://www.twitch.tv/hunterofrares I'm not affiliated with them, but they have helped me before.

Comment: There's no macro capable of doing this, you would need a specially coded add-on. It's possible to code this in LUA because similar add-ons exist (such as Spy!, Vanas KoS), but those are used for scanning for enemy faction players.

Comment: I very much appreciate all responses I think @Sorean must have misunderstood my post. As a Beast Master hunter in WOW, it is common practice to "camp" a certain spawn location if there is NO other hunter already there. Most of the time there are more than one spawn point and if that one is already "camped" you move on to the next one (spawn points show on the map). If all are occupied, you come back at another time. At least that is the common practice on my realm (Hyjal). Lastly, the circumstance that gives a hunter "privilege" is the fact that they were there first. Only ONE can TAME it.

Comment: I don't believe I misunderstood you. I also main a BM hunter, have since vanilla. And yes that's common practice (even when I've been camping, moving on when someone is already at a spot), what I'm saying is that there's no "right" to that spot. It's common practice and respect, but there are jerks in the world. Sending a message would more likely end up having the other person kill the spawn than moving on. People are petty.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use a /s Macro while standing close to them so it shows up on their screen. Some people block whispers from strangers and party invites too.

```
/s <Text you want to say>
```